# Device that allows the use a stenomask without having to hold it with one's hand

Tags: microphones

I am looking for some device that would allow me to use a [stenomask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenomask) without having to hold it with my hand (i.e., to have a hands-free stenomask). I plan to use the stenomask for speech recognition with my computer.

The only options I have found so far are:

1. [Vocedit's Hands Free Mask Stand](http://vocedit.com/product6.html), which can accommodate either the Martel or the TalkTech stenomask:

[image][image]

[image][image]

[image][image][image]

2. The [Sylencer SmartMic SM 200](http://talktech.com/products/speech-recognition-smartmic/) has a snap-on head-strap option available, but the strap is not comfortable.

   They do seem to have some plan to improve the hands-free option though, according to this [Facebook comment](https://www.facebook.com/talktechnologies/posts/1779587142303957?comment_id=1779951535600851&notif_t=feed_comment&notif_id=1474499281861945):

[image]

3. Phil Kaufman's [Voxrite hands-free option](http://www.voxrite.com/shop/), but they do not to sold their hands-free device anymore (I was told they might sell them again in the future, to be checked in ~six months).

[image]

What are other devices achieving that goal?

Any price is good.

Comment: You seem to answer your own question quite well.

Comment: @NZKshatriya I would be glad to hear about other solutions. I'm especially interested in hands-free solutions that do not involve placing a stand on the desk, so that one can move one's head while still using the stenomask.

Comment: There are references to a military version that is akin to a headset mount, but I have yet to come across it.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Thanks, I would be very interested! I was indeed thinking about some design similar to gas mask, headset mount, or even helmet. Please let me know if you find them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vox Helpers](https://www.facebook.com/vox.helpers)' stenomask stand:

- supports the [Sylencer SmartMic SM 100 and 200](http://talktech.com/products/speech-recognition-smartmic/)
- C-clamp is 2" wide and easily attaches to most work spaces. Other options are available for an extra charge:
- Mask can be easily removed in a second:
- You can bind to the shape that you need no matter what you have to clamp it to.

I don't know the price though, and their [website](http://vox-helpers.com/) is down. It is unclear whether they can still be purchased.

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

C-hook that holds the Smartmic or mask:

[image]

Close-up of Smartmic/mask holder without cover:

[image]

C-clamp is 2" wide and easily attaches to most work spaces. Other options are available for an extra charge:

[image]

C-clamp in horizontal position:

[image]

Mask can be easily removed in a second:

[image]

You can bind to the shape that you need no matter what you have to clamp it to:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @NZKshatriya it is encouraged on Stack Exchange websites to answer one's own questions. Besides, it took me some time to find some solutions (more exactly, a nice guy emailed me pointers to these two solutions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HANDSFREEDesign](https://www.etsy.com/listing/479442710/handsfree-gadget?ref=shop_home_active_1)'s HANDSFREE Gadget:

- It is a strap that attaches to the [Sylencer SmartMic SM 100 or 200](http://talktech.com/products/speech-recognition-smartmic/)
- It cost 39.99 USD
- Only ships within United States. (takes 1 or 2 weeks to ship)
- It can be used on both the regular mouth piece and the large mouth piece that covers your nose.
- The device is supposed to have great grip (I haven't tried)
- The grip is adjustable.

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The new Martel Dragon Stenomask has an all-digital USB microphone that improves the speech recognition. Setting the new Standard for real-time voice recognition for court reporters. see it here. [Revolutionary Dragon Stenomask for Court Reporters.](https://www.martelelectronics.com/revolutionary-dragon-stenomask-for-voice-recognition/)

Thanks Carl